# ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder GetFile synchronous

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp

I need to create a database / check for its existance at my program start.

```
public async Task CopyDatabaseIfNotExists(string dbPath)
{
    var nExpectedFolder = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

            try
            {
                await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(dbPath); //nExpectedFolder.GetFileAsync(dbPath);/// ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("preinstalledDB.db");
                // No exception means it exists
                return;
            }
            catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
            {
                // The file obviously doesn't exist
            }

        (... some other stuff)
```

My application can't and shouldn't be run before this test has been completed.

Therefore I wanted to change my calls to be synchronous.

However, I only see

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync
```

.GetFile doesn't exist.

What would be the way to make the call synchronous?

Comment: I believe the proper way to handle this is to use await on this method from its calling method.  And before that use await on the calling method as well, all the way up the scope chain until you're calling from a constructor.  Or use an "async void" method to call it if you must which will run it synchronously.  [link]https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem with async.

If you do everything async, for example

```
private async void DoThis()
{
   await SomethingA();
   await SomethingB();

   return;
}
```

Then you can be sure that SomethingB() will NEVER be called before SomethingA() has been awaited.

That's the reason why you have to do everything async once you do something async in a subroutine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .NET APIs from `System.IO` to read files synchronously. You can get the `StorageFolder.Path` property from the `LocalFolder` and pass the path name to .NET.

The [`FileStream` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47ek66wy(v=vs.110).aspx) takes a `path` and a `mode` and from there you can read and write synchronously or asynchronously.

Comment: I think I already tried that. Could you post the equivalent code for "ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(dbPath);"?